# Measuring tool crashes on QGIS 3.22.5

Tags: qgis-3, measurements

When I open the measuring tool to measure distances QGIS crashes. I am using  the LTR Version 3.22.5. I have two small a layers in the projected to EPSG:28355 and base layers sourced from rest services in CRS EPSG:3857. My project CRS is set to EPSG:28355 and the default layer CRS is EPSG:4326.

I am aiming to estimate slope between contours using the measuring tool which then causes the crash, however I would like to use the measuring tool for other purposes. It simply will not work.

Comment: Do you get error messages in the log console? If yes, what are they?

Comment: Are you referring to the balloon in the far right of the QGIS status bar? If it is, there are no error messages contained therein.